# Is way to upload header comma in csv?

Tags: php, csv

Hello Friend i have text array with comma selerated with double coutes but when i push record in csv that comma seperated value convert into two header can you please help me to solved this issue .

please find bellow string.
for example : i need "South West, London & Support Office L1" in one colume

```
$datestr ='First Name,Last Name,Company,Type,Email,Attendance Status,Invited By,Payroll      No,Pharmacy No,Pharmacy Name,RM,RSM,Accomodation Friday,Accomodation Saturday,Job_Title,"Business Partner Session","Awards Evening","North & Central L1","North & Central L2","South East L1","South East & Warehouse L2","South West, London & Support Office L1","South West, London and Support Office L2';

$sessstr = "First Name,"."Last Name,"."Company,"."Type,"."Email,"."Attendance Status,"."Invited By,"."Payroll No,"."Pharmacy No,"."Pharmacy Name,"."RM,"."RSM,"."Accomodation Friday,"."Accomodation Saturday,"."Job_Title,";
        $datestr = "Jaikishan, Keswani,Day Lewis,jaikishan.keswani@daylewisplc.co.uk,Yes,Colin,,,1,,,,Yes,Yes,PHP Developer,";
        foreach($sessions as $k=>$ses){
            $sessstr .= '"'.$ses['session_name'].'",';
            $datestr .= 'Yes,';
        }
        $datestr = substr($datestr,0,-1);
        $sessstr = substr($sessstr,0,-1);

        $sessstr = $sessstr.",European Welcome Dinner,"."Accommodation By Invitation Letter,"."Notes,"."Awards Evening Food Option,"."Dietary Requirements";
        $datestr = $datestr.",,,,,";

        header('Content-Type: application/excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
        $data = array(
                $sessstr,
                $datestr
        );

        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        foreach ( $data as $line ) {
            $val = explode(",", $line);

            fputcsv($fp, $val);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you're using to do this. If you're using PHPs native fputcsv and fgetcsv functions it shouldn't present with this issue.

Comment: But when i open csv that "South West, London & Support Office L1" conver into South West and  London & Support Office L1 . can you please help me to solve this

Comment: How are you writing that line?

Comment: i am update my code please check

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHPs CSV functions you should put your data in arrays:

```
$datestr =['First Name','Last Name','Company','Type','Email','Attendance Status','Invited By','Payroll      No','Pharmacy No','Pharmacy Name','RM','RSM','Accomodation Friday','Accomodation Saturday','Job_Title','Business Partner Session',"Awards Evening","North & Central L1","North & Central L2","South East L1","South East & Warehouse L2","South West, London & Support Office L1","South West, London and Support Office L2"];

$sessstr = ["First Name","Last Name","Company","Type","Email","Attendance Status","Invited By","Payroll No","Pharmacy No","Pharmacy Name","RM","RSM","Accomodation Friday","Accomodation Saturday","Job_Title" ];
$datestr = ["Jaikishan", "Keswani","Day Lewis","jaikishan.keswani@daylewisplc.co.uk","Yes","Colin","","","1","","","","Yes","Yes","PHP Developer"];
 foreach($sessions as $k=>$ses){
        $sessstr[] = $ses['session_name'];
        $datestr[] = 'Yes';
    }
    //$datestr = substr($datestr,0,-1);
    //$sessstr = substr($sessstr,0,-1);

    $sessstr = array_merge($sessstr,["European Welcome Dinner","Accommodation By Invitation Letter","Notes","Awards Evening Food Option","Dietary Requirements" ];
    $datestr = array_merge($datestr,[ "","","","","","" ]);

    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
    $data = array(
            $sessstr,
            $datestr
    );

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ( $data as $line ) {
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```